# Why do we need the highlighted sentence below in [dcl.init]/(6.2)?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

[[dcl.init]/(6.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-6.2)

> If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, its padding
> bits are initialized to zero bits and each non-static data member,
> each non-virtual base class subobject, and, **if the object is not a
> base class subobject**, each virtual base class subobject is
> zero-initialized;

AFAICT, the sentence above is confusing and dispensable. What do they mean by the **object** that is not a base class subobject?

Comment: It refers to the object from the first sentence of that paragraph: *To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:*

Comment: @NathanOliver Why can't we just eliminate that sentence from the paragraph? It would be less confusing.

Comment: fwiw, already "its" in "its padding bits are..." refers to the same object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The writing of a technical specification is a bit like programming. [dcl.init]/6 can therefore be thought of as a kind of function: the function which performs zero-initialization on an object. This function gets called when a complete object is zero-initialized.

Here's some pseudo-code for the general structure of [dcl.init]/6:

```
void zero_init(T &t)
{
  if(zero_init_1(t)) return; //Executes rule 6.1; returns false if rule 6.1 doesn't apply to T.
  if(zero_init_2(t)) return; //Executes rule 6.2; returns false if rule 6.2 doesn't apply to T.
  if(zero_init_3(t)) return; //Executes rule 6.3; returns false if rule 6.3 doesn't apply to T.
  ...
}
```

The important thing here is `zero_init_2`, the code that represents section 6.2:

```
bool zero_init_2(T &t)
  if(T is class && T is !union)
  {
    zero_init_padding_bit(t);
    for(auto &base : non_virtual_bases(t))
      zero_init(base);
    for(auto &member : members(t))
      zero_init(member);

    if(!is_base_class(t))
      for(auto &base : virtual_bases(t))
        zero_init(base);

    return true; //I did initialization here.
  }
  return false; //No initialization done here.
}
```

You suggested:

> I would replace "and, if the object is not a base class subobject, each virtual base class subobject is zero-initialized" by "and each virtual base class subobject of the most derived object is zero-initialized".

The code for this would be as follows:

```
bool zero_init_2(T &t)
  if(T is class && T is !union)
  {
    zero_init_padding_bit(t);
    for(auto &base : non_virtual_bases(t))
      zero_init(base);
    for(auto &member : members(t))
      zero_init(member);

    auto &u = get_most_derived_object(t)
    for(auto &base : virtual_bases(u))
      zero_init(base);

    return true; //I did initialization here.
  }
  return false; //No initialization done here.
}
```

In your suggested version, there is no conditional. So there is no conditional in the pseudo-code either. But `zero_init` is a function that can invoke `zero_init_2`; that is, it is *recursive*.

This means that virtual base classes could be zero-initialized multiple times. Indeed, it would be infinitely recursive on any type with virtual base classes. `get_most_derived_object` will return the most derived object. The non-union virtual base class subobjects of this object include... the one we're currently initializing. So we will recursively reinitialize ourselves, never terminating.

The original wording ensures that the virtual base classes will only be zero-initialized once. Yours does not.

Comment: "But `zero_init` is a function that can invoke `zero_init_2`; that is, it is recursive." In which conditions does this happen?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet: Look back at the specification. Section [dcl.init]/6 defines what it means to do zero initialization. Therefore in our analogy, that is what `zero_init` does. And if you look at the text, 6.2 (`zero_init_2` in the analogy) is performed in cases where 6.1 doesn't apply. That is, if the type is not a scalar. So if `T` has a non-virtual subobject that isn't a scalar, then 6.2 will apply to it. *Recursively* for every subobject of `T`.

Comment: Could you give an example where a virtual base class could be infinitely recursive? I just couldn't find one.

Comment: @François-MarieArouet: Remember: we're only talking about in *your* wording. In the actual wording, there is no infinite recursion. In any case, it would happen with any class that satisfies 6.2 and which has a virtual base class. This is because the `get_most_derived_object(t)` call for the virtual base class will get the original object, then iterate through its virtual base classes and re-initialize *itself*.

Comment: I can see you improved quite a bit your answer with your last edit. It makes a lot of sense to me now. Thank you for your patience. Great answer, by the way!

Answer (score 2):

"The object" is of type `T`. This sentence simply applies the logic of initializing virtual bases to zero-initialization. It is always the most derived object that initializes virtual bases. For instance.

```
class A {
  //
};

class B : public virtual A {
  //
};

class C : public B {
  //
};

static B b; // The zero initialization of `b` also zero initializes an `A` sub-object
static C c; // The zero initialization of the 'B' sub-object **does not** include
            // zero-initialization of an `A` sub-object.
```

The highlighted sentence serves a purpose here, and is not superfluous.

Comment: I still think the sentence is unnecessary and confusing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @François-MarieArouet - We can debate "confusing". You'd have to demonstrate "unnecessary" by showing **existing** verbiage that describes the same desired behavior. I doubt you'd be able to find it.

Comment: I would replace "and, if the object is not a base class subobject, each virtual base class subobject is zero-initialized" by "**and each virtual base class subobject of the most derived object is zero-initialized**".

Comment: @François-MarieArouet At the point where the zero-init of a subobject runs, we must not start any initialization of virtual base class subobjects which might already have been initialized. I.e. I think the *"if the object"* refers to the current (sub)object being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Example A:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct VirtualBase
{
    int x;
};

struct Derived : virtual VirtualBase
{};

struct Complete : Derived, virtual VirtualBase
{
    Complete()
        : VirtualBase{42}
        , Derived()
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Complete c;
    std::cout << c.x;
}
```

How does the initialization of `Complete c;` work?

- We start with default-initialization of the `Complete` object. This calls the default ctor.
- The default-ctor starts by initializing the virtual base classes ([class.base.init](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-13.1)).

  - We do an aggregate-initialization of the `VirtualBase` subobject and set the `int` to `42`.
- Then, we initialize the `Derived` subobject. The form of initialization is `Derived()` which causes value-initialization of the subobject.

  - We follow https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-8.1.2 which causes the `Derived` subobject to be zero-initialized. Now we finally get to the OP.

> if the object is not a base class subobject, each virtual base class subobject is zero-initialized;

The `Derived` object we're initializing ***is** a base class subobject of `Complete`*. Hence we **do not** zero-initialize the `VirtualBase` base class object of `Derived`.

Without the subclause *"if the object is not a base class subobject"*, we would have zero-initialized the `VirtualBase` subobject of `Derived`. This would have meant to zero-initialize the `int` member, setting it to `0`. Because this happens *after* we already wrote `42` into it, setting it to `0` would have overwritten the value.

---

Example B:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct VirtualBase
{
    int x;
};

struct Derived : virtual VirtualBase
{};

struct Complete : Derived, virtual VirtualBase
{
    Complete()
        : Derived()
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Complete c;
    std::cout << c.x;
}
```

The constructor of `Complete` lacks any mem-initializer for `VirtualBase`, so it will *default-initialize* that virtual base class. `Derived` on the other hand is value-initialized, which causes zero-initialization. Since `Derived` is a base class subobject here, it will **not** zero-initialize the virtual base. It remains uninitialized and we get UB in the `cout << c.x`.

You get some funny output with gcc and clang but unfortunately I couldn't get the sanitizers to report on it. [Live demo](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/vefPeb)

Comment: Example A: "The virtual base class object is initialized first, before the non-virtual base classes". Where in the Standard does it say this? I'm asking this because after [this change](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc74521892e88d24) in Example B, the virtual base class object is also initialized before the non-virtual base class Derived.

Comment: @François-MarieArouet https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-13.1

Comment: I just can't see the relationship between these two examples and the relevance (or irrelevance) of the alluded sentence in my question. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet Sure, but it'll take some time. Short version is: The sentence _prevents_ `Derived` from zero-initializing its virtual base `VirtualBase` _in the initialization sequence for `Complete`_.

Comment: But the context in [\[dcl.init\]/(6.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-6.2) is one where  your `Complete` class would be **zero-initialized**, not default- initialized. I don't see how that could be relevant to my question.

Comment: @François-MarieArouet Initialization is defined "recursively" from outermost (complete) object to base classes and data members. While `Complete` is default-init, the inner `Derived` subobject is zero-init.